# SQL Server Left Join producing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, left-join, sql-server-2019

I have 3 tables, Budgets, Income, and Expenses.

**Budget** table:

[image]

**Income** table:

[image]

**Expenses** table:

[image]

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    Budgets.BudgetID, Budgets.BudgetName, Budgets.Username_FK,   
    Budgets.BudgetAmount, Budgets.SavePercentage,
    Expenses.ExpensesID, Expenses.ExpensesAmount, Expenses.ExpensesCategory,
    Income.IncomeID, Income.IncomeAmount, Income.IncomeCategory
FROM 
    Budgets
LEFT JOIN 
    Income ON Budgets.BudgetID = Income.BudgetID_FK
LEFT JOIN 
    Expenses ON Budgets.BudgetID = Expenses.BudgetID_FK
WHERE 
    BudgetName = '2019
```

And the results are as follows:

[image]

Based on my `Income` table, there is only 1 record tied to `BudgetID = 3`, but in the left join, it duplicates.

Ideally, I would want it to return "null" on the duplicates. How do I do this?

Comment: Images of data really don't help us help you here. Please take the time to provide sample data in a consumable format; either tabular formatted `text` or (even better) DDL and DML statements.

Comment: As for your question, why would you not expect 4 rows for `BudgetID` 3? It has `3` rows in the  `Expenses` table.

Comment: @Larnu If you look at the **Income Table**, there is only 1 row tied to **BudgetID 3**, however, if you look at the **Left Join Results**, it returns 3 additional records.

Comment: You are getting 3 more results because of the 3 additional rows in expenses table for the same budget ID

Comment: Your results include one row for each `ExpensesID`, which is exactly what your query is asking for. These are NOT duplicate rows. Change the `ExpensesAmounts` to four different numbers to see that more clearly. The question is, what do you want to do with those four numbers? Your question doesn't make that clear, so everyone so far is just guessing at your intentions.

Comment: @EricBrandt Sorry if the question was a little ambiguous, didn't really knew how to put the question together. The end goal was to take the total of the BudgetAmount, ExpensesAmount, and IncomeAmount and perform some calculations. Someone provided an answer to what I was looking for. Thank you for taking the time to write on this post.

Comment: You are not saying what you want your query to do. You just say you don't want "duplicates", and you don't clearly say what you mean by that either. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several rows in `expenses` per `budgetID`, so your join produces that many rows. I tend to suspect that the same situation could happen with `income` too.

If you want one row per `budgetID`, then one option is pre-aggregation and a `left join` (or `outer apply`). Say you want the total expense and income per budget, you would do:

```
select b.*, e.expenseAmount, i.amountAmount
from budgets b
left join (
    select budgetID_FK, sum(expenseAmount) expenseAmount 
    from expenses 
    group by budgetID_FK
) e on e.budgetID_FK = b.budgetID
left join (
    select budgetID_FK, sum(incomeAmount) incomeAmount 
    from income 
    group by budgetID_FK
) i on i.budgetID_FK = b.budgetID
```

Now you are grouping rows in the dependent tables by `budgetID`, so you can't see the other columns of these tables, such as `incomeCategory` or `expenseCategory` (which have multiple values per `budgetID`).

Answer (score 0):

For budgetID 3 , you have 4 expenses( distinct expense IDs) of 50.00 in your expense table for the same user. I think what you would want is the total expenses of same category and budget ID i.e budgetID 3 in this case

```
SELECT 
Budgets.BudgetID, Budgets.BudgetName, Budgets.Username_FK,   
Budgets.BudgetAmount, Budgets.SavePercentage,
Income.IncomeID, Income.IncomeAmount, Income.IncomeCategory,
ex.ExpensesCategory,
ex.Total_ExpensesAmount, 

FROM Budgets 
LEFT JOIN Income ON Budgets.BudgetID = Income.BudgetID_FK
LEFT JOIN (Select BudgetID_FK, ExpensesCategory, SUM(ExpensesAmount) as Total_ExpensesAmount
           FROM Expenses 
           GROUP BY BudgetID_FK, ExpensesCategory) ex ON Budgets.BudgetID = ex.BudgetID_FK
WHERE BudgetName = '2019'
```